# Material UI - gutterBottom vs paragraph, difference?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

What is the difference between these?

I'm looking at the Typography Component API and there's `gutterBottom` and `paragraph` props that documented the exact same thing, if true, margin bottom will be 0. Here's the link to the Component API: https://material-ui.com/api/typography/

Answer (score 11):

There are two parts of difference.

---

First,the css unit is different.The em unit for gutterBottom is relative.1em equals to the font-size of the father component.

```
gutterBottom: {
    marginBottom: '0.35em',
},
paragraph: {
    marginBottom: 16,
},
```

Second,paragraph is used to choose the basic component of Typography.If paragraph is true ,the Typography is "p".If paragraph is false,check the two default setting, or the Typography will be "span".

```
const Component =
    componentProp ||
    (paragraph ? 'p' : headlineMapping[variant] || defaultHeadlineMapping[variant]) ||
    'span';
```

Answer (score 2):

Well they may cause a similar look (0.35em margin vs 16px margin) but they are more concerned with semantics. `paragraph` will also result in a `p` element rather than a `div` element.

The documentation could be improved. Feel free to raise an issue or even open a PR.